# How to take the bounds of the web part(chromium view) in electron

Tags: electron

```
----title----------------
----menu------------------
-x,y
-
-        
-               content
-               i want't get screen position this area
-------------------------------------------
```

The position and size results of the BrowserWindow.getContentBounds()method include title and menu bar

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but if you are asking how to capture a section of the screen you can use the [capturePage](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wincapturepagerect-callback) method.

> win.capturePage([rect, ]callback)
>
> ```
> rect Rectangle (optional) - The bounds to capture
>
> callback Function
>     image NativeImage
> ```
>
> Captures a snapshot of the page within rect. Upon completion callback
>   will be called with callback(image). The image is an instance of
>   NativeImage that stores data of the snapshot. Omitting rect will
>   capture the whole visible page.

Comment: Thanks, I want to get the position of the Chromuim View on the screen.
Because I want to use the system mouse API to click on the page